# UITableViewCell with a UITableView not displaying

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a custom UITableViewCell that contains its own TableView. However, when I am executing the app, the nested TableView will not display at all. It's not calling the delegate function that returns the reusable cell. optionsList is linked to the TableView pictured below. Not sure what is preventing it from appearing on the screen. The `MultiChoiceCell` created via a xib file needs to basically construct a tableview with a label at the top and a tableview below containing a scrollable table view that contains cells simply with a label that are check-marked when selected.

Code in ViewController sets options array with label values that need to be loaded in the nested table view named optionsList:

```
class MultipleChoiceViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    @IBOutlet weak var surveyQuestionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionsList: UITableView!{
        didSet{
            self.optionsList.delegate = self
            self.optionsList.dataSource = self
            self.optionsList.rowHeight = 45
            let nibOptionCell = UINib(nibName: "SimpleTableCell", bundle: nil)
            self.optionsList.register(nibOptionCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SimpleTableCell")
            self.optionsList.reloadData()
        }
    }
    var options = [String](){
        didSet{
            self.optionsList.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return options.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let return_cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SimpleTableCell", for: indexPath) as! SimpleTableViewCell
        return_cell.optionLabel.text = options[indexPath.row]
        return return_cell
    }

}
```

[image]

Code in the ViewController:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.surveyQuestionsTableView.delegate = self
        self.surveyQuestionsTableView.dataSource = self

        self.surveyQuestionsTableView.rowHeight = 285
        let nibFreeResponse = UINib(nibName: "FreeResponseCell", bundle: nil)
        surveyQuestionsTableView.register(nibFreeResponse, forCellReuseIdentifier: "freeResponseCell")

        let nibMultiChoice = UINib(nibName: "MultiChoiceCell", bundle: nil)
        surveyQuestionsTableView.register(nibMultiChoice, forCellReuseIdentifier: "multiChoiceCell")
    }
    //return number of cells to display
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return survey_questions["survey"].count
    }

    //generate cell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let survey_question = survey_questions["survey"][indexPath.row]
        if(survey_question["type"] == "freeResponse"){
            let return_cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "freeResponseCell", for: indexPath) as! FreeResponseViewCell
            return_cell.surveyQuestionLabel.text = survey_question["question"].string!
            return_cell.surveyResponseField.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
            return_cell.surveyResponseField.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)

            return return_cell
        }

        if(survey_question["type"] == "multipleChoice"){
            let return_cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "multiChoiceCell", for: indexPath) as! MultipleChoiceViewCell
            return_cell.surveyQuestionLabel.text = survey_question["question"].string!
            return_cell.options = survey_question["answers"].arrayObject as! [String]
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                return_cell.optionsList.reloadData()
            }


            return return_cell
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you adding the options list to the tableView when it's been set up in Interface Builder?

Comment: Also, have you declared the cell identifier for the list of options in Interface Builder? If not, it needs to be declared in the class. Recommended you changes the name of the individual item cell as "OptionCell" or similar to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yes the cell identifiers are properly declared. The cell for `optionsList` is another standalone xib containing a single cell with a label with some spacing on the right end to make room for the checkmark icon.

Comment: You shouldn't be adding the cell for optionsList as a subview, rather register its nib for the reuse identifier.

Comment: There's also a standard cell type for what you want for the option item, no need to roll your own :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `reloadData()` in `MultipleChoiceViewCell` setupTable. Call `setupTable()` from required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder):

```
//...

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style , reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setUpTable()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setUpTable()
}

func setUpTable(){
    self.optionsList.delegate = self
    self.optionsList.dataSource = self
    self.optionsList.rowHeight = 45
    self.addSubview(optionsList)
    self.reloadData()
}

//...
```

Comment: Sorry I just updated my post. Instead of setupTable function, I'm calling the code in the `didSet` property observer. Not sure if that is not an advisable version, but the previous version wasn't even calling the `numberOfRows` function.

Comment: Call reloadData() at last line of didSet.

Comment: `self.optionsList.reloadData()` added but nothing changed. I should at least see a blank table view but as you can see from the emulator screenshot, that's not even displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Call a setup function from your init methods...

```
func setUpTable() {
    optionsList.delegate = self
    optionsList.dataSource = self
    optionsList.rowHeight = 45

    // Register your option cell
    let nibOptionCell = UINib(nibName: "AnswerOptionCell", bundle: nil)
        optionsList.register(nibOptionCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "AnswerOptionCell")

}
```

Dequeue the AnswerOptionCell as usual.

Recommend that you keep the reuse identifiers the same as the cell class names to avoid mistakes.

Comment: I am using `didSet` for `optionsList` instead, so I believe you were looking at the older code. I registered the nib in the `didSet` but I'm not even able to see a table view appear on the screen. Not sure why it's not even displaying an empty tableview

Comment: There's no registering the nib in `didSet`, rather you're adding the table view *again* as a subview when it's already been set-up in IB. Apologies if the code above is old!

Comment: I just updated my `didSet` code above. Please have a look at it now. Either way, I'm not sure what's preventing an empty tableview from appearing with no cells below the label text

Comment: Have you used View Debugging to check if there is an empty table view in the view hierarchy? Try setting the background color of your table view and cells to different colours to help the debugging process, e.g. make the inner table view red and the option cells green.

Comment: Cool feature! I used it and looks like the nested table view is not even there, which is odd because it's shown in IB

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but a potentially better approach would be to split the table view into sections, one for each question. You can then create cells for the various different question types, including a cell for an option. Then return the number of options (plus title or other content) in the` numberOfRowsInSection` func and set the relevant cells based on the indexPath. You then don't need to embed table views inside table views, and there's no conflict with trying to scroll, and the user sees all the available options at once... Just a suggestion!

Comment: Might be better to stick with the current method since the focus is to figure out how to get the UI to at least display the tableview. Using the View Debugging, I got `Position and width are ambiguous for UITableView`

Comment: Update: Well this is really odd...The TableView now appears after I performed a Clean Build Folder

Comment: Check the constraints of the table view.